# Change Background Color of FloatingActionButton in material-ui ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, floating-action-button

I have a set of FloatingActionButton that I am using from `material-ui` in my ReactJS code as

```
<div className="callActionButtons">
  <FloatingActionButton style={{padding: '5px'}}>
    <VoiceSettingsIcon/>
  </FloatingActionButton>
  <FloatingActionButton style={{padding: '5px'}} onTouchTap={this.endCall}>
    <CallEndIcon  />
  </FloatingActionButton>
  <FloatingActionButton style={{padding: '5px'}}>
    <VideoIcon/>
  </FloatingActionButton>
</div>
```

The UI currently looks like

[image]

I want to apply a `backgroundColor` property to the `FloatingActionButton` so that the center one has a `red background` and looks like

[image]

going through the documentation of [`FloatingActionButton`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/floating-action-button). I tried to provide styles using

```
<FloatingActionButton style={{padding: '5px'}} 
         iconStyles={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} 
         onTouchTap={this.endCall}>
```

nothing changed

I also tried providing background color with inline style like

```
   <FloatingActionButton style={{padding: '5px', backgroundColor: 'red'}} 
         onTouchTap={this.endCall}>
```

With this I get the following display

[image]

I can't quite figure out how to get the desired result. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Change the icon background-color, send `backgroundColor={red500}`  as props. Here `red500` is desired color. You can also pass string or color code

```
<FloatingActionButton style={{padding: '5px'}} backgroundColor={red500}
    onTouchTap={this.endCall}>
     <CallEndIcon  />
</FloatingActionButton>
```

You can get color this way:

```
 import {red500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors'
```

Comment: It was right there in front of my eyes. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks